# Request scoped injection is not getting mocked

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, dependency-injection, jestjs, nestjs

I am trying to mock the return value of a provider, but for some reason, it's clearing out the mock.

**Module1.ts**

```js
@Module({
  providers: [Service1],
  exports: [Service1],
})
export class Module1 {}
```

**Service1.ts**

```js
@Injectable({
  scope: Scope.REQUEST,
})
export class Service1 {
  constructor() {
  }
  public getVal() {
    return '3';
  }
}
```

**Service2.ts**

```js
@Injectable()
export class Service2 {
  constructor(private readonly service1: Service1) {}
  private someFn() {
    this.service1.getVal();
  }
}
```

**Service2.test.ts**

```js
let service1;
let service2;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [Module1],
      providers: [Service2],
    }).compile();
    service2= await module.resolve(Service2);
    service1= await module.resolve(Service1);
  });
it('some test',()=> {
jest.spyOn(service1,'getVal').mockReturnValue('2'); //This should mock getVal function and return 2.
service2.someFn();
});
```

But, the mock is not happening. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no chance for `service1.getVal` to not be mocked, the mock is very straightforward. That it doesn't affect `service2.someFn()` means that `service2` doesn't use the same `Service1` instance as the one that was mocked.

As [the documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes) states:

> REQUEST
>
> A new instance of the provider is created exclusively for each incoming request. The instance is garbage-collected after the request has completed processing.

This means that `Service1` instances are unique. The one that belongs to `Service2` needs to be mocked:

```
jest.spyOn(service2['service1'], 'getVal').mockReturnValue('2')
```

Comment: It would make sense to use service2['service1'] and try to mock. But, service1 is a private member of service2. In my opinion, we wouldn't be able to access it.
nevertheless, the solution is to provide service1 with a mock value. 

providers: [
{provide:Service1, useValue: mockedValue}
]

Comment: It's possible to access it for testing purposes. You can consider it reflection. You could use `Reflect.get(service2, 'service1')` instead of `service2['service1']` but it does the same thing and is longer to type. Yes, it's possible to solve this with DI, too.

Answer (score 0):

Each call to `resolve` "creates a unique instance of the provider" for scoped providers. When running a test like this you will want to create a contextId so that everything is bulled from the same DI sub tree.

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [Module1],
      providers: [Service2],
    }).compile();
    const contextId = ContextIdFactory.create();
    service2 = await module.resolve(Service2, contextId);
    service1 = await module.resolve(Service1, contextId);
  });
```

https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/module-ref#resolving-scoped-providers